# Native ad Size: Can I use Native ads in the 2 column Grid of recyclerview?

Tags: android-layout, admob, ads, native-ads

Admob Native ad Size for android: Can I use Native ads in the 2-column Grid of recycler view as I showed in the UI?
Is there any policy restriction of google Admob?

[image]

Comment: Hi,how did you resolve this? please give some code